# Object being released too early?

Tags: iphone, ios, memory, memory-management, memory-leaks

I've been hitting my head against a wall for 2 days now, trying to figure out what the heck is wrong with my code. So far, nothing. The only thing I've discovered is the fact that an object is trying to call release on itself and it hasn't been instantiated yet. (although, for some reason it doesn't happen 100% of the time, just whenever the heck it thinks)

Let me explain the problem (maybe I'm overlooking something, I hope you guys can shed some light into my darkness)

My model object

```
Person {
  NSString *name;
  NSNumber *age;
}

@property(nonatomic, retain) NSNumber* TheAge;
@property(nonatomic, retain) NSString *TheName;
```

My implementation

```
@synthesize TheName = name;
@synthesize TheAge = age;

+(Person*)personFromDictionary:(NSDictionary*)dic {
  Person* newPerson = [[[Person alloc] init]autorelease];
  newPerson.theAge = [dic objectForKey:kAge];
  newPerson.theName = [dic objectForKey:kName];

  return newPerson;
}

-(void)dealloc {
  self.TheAge = nil;
  self.TheName = nil;
}
```

I have a "collector thread" that reads a JSON array from the server, downloads it and parses it into a dictionary. Every entry in the dictionary corresponds to a person object
This thread is a different class simply using the Person model

The thread does something like this (in an autorelease pool)

```
NSDictionary *parsedDict = download.returnValue;

NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
Person *tmpPerson = personFromDictionary

[entryDictionary setObject:tmpPerson forKey:kAge];

[pool release];

[self updateEntries:entryDictionary];

-(void)updateEntries:(NSMutableDictionary*)updatedDict {
   NSArray *keys = [updatedDict allKeys];
   for(NSString *key in allKeys){
        Person *entry = [updatedDict valueForKey:key];
        [entriesLock lock];
        [currentPersonEntries setObject:entry forKey:key];
        [entriesLock unlock];

    }
}
```

When I get the crash (which happens randomly for some damn reason, I get the stack trace as follows

person dealloc

person setTheAge (bam crash)

I'm guessing because the setter would look something like this

```
-(void)setTheAge:(NSString*)theAge {
  [theAge retain];
  [age release]; // it doesn't exist for some reason???
  age = theAge;
}
```

How can I protect vs this type of thing?

Comment: Did you try removing autorelease in Person* newPerson = [[[Person alloc] init]autorelease];

Comment: By the way, I haven't tried it on the code sample above, but I'd wager that the static analyzer (shift-command-B) would probably generate all sorts of warnings about the above code. If you're just getting into Objective C, the warnings reported by the static analyzer can be very useful. You should have _zero_ warnings from the analyzer. I think my answer below is a more constructive answer (rather than wading through a bunch of warnings), but I just wanted to suggest that you check out this wonderful little tool.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A couple of thoughts.

First, you have:

```
Person {
    NSString *name;
    NSNumber *age;
}

@property(nonatomic, retain) NSNumber* TheAge;
@property(nonatomic, retain) NSString *TheName;
```

And in your implementation, you have:

```
@synthesize TheName = name;
@synthesize TheAge = age;
```

Apple no longer recommends you define your ivars explicitly, but let your synthesize statement take care of it (probably because if you misspell one of those, you can end up with an extra, unintended ivar). So you might just want:

```
@interface Person : NSObject

@property(nonatomic, retain) NSNumber* theAge;
@property(nonatomic, retain) NSString* theName;

@end
```

Also, when naming your ivars, the emerging standard is (but, of course, you can do what you want) to use underscores for ivars, and starting your variable names with lowercase ... uppercase for classes, lowercase for variables, e.g.:

```
@synthesize theName = _theName;
@synthesize theAge = _theAge;
```

Second, in your `dealloc` you're setting those ivars to nil. While that's the correct way to release in ARC code, in non-ARC code, you should just use your ivars, and use the release command:

```
- (void)dealloc {
    [_theAge release];
    [_theName release];

    [super dealloc];
}
```

Third, are you writing that setter `setTheAge` or are you guessing what the compiler is doing itself? Your code can probably be improved (you're using a local variable which is the same as your property, which is just confusing, you'd want to do key value notifications, etc.), but I won't address that because you'd be better off just letting the compiler do its own setter unless there is something else that you're trying to accomplish. Let me know.

Fourth, your `-(Person*)personFromDictionary:(NSDictionary*)dic` is a curious method. I'd suggest writing your own init, like:

```
- (Person*)initFromDictionary:(NSDictionary*) dic 
{
    self = [super init]; // I always inherit from NSObject, in which case you'd have this line

    if (self)
    {
        self.theAge  = [dic objectForKey:kAge];
        self.theName = [dic objectForKey:kName];
    }

    return self;
}
```

This way, you could create your Person object like:

```
Person *aPerson = [[Person alloc] initWithDictionary:entryDictionary];
```

Your current implementation assumes the `Person` object already exists (because you preface the method name with "-" rather than "+"), but then creates a new one. It's a little strange. You might be able to do something like that, but the above code pattern is more commonplace and achieves what I think you want.

Finally, I'm not sure what you're trying to do with `updateEntries`, so I'm not sure what to suggest there, but I don't quite get the `updateEntries` outside of your pool, whether you meant it to be a dictionary full of Person objects, etc. If you describe what you're trying to accomplish there, I'd be happy to give you my two cents on that, too.

**Update:**

By the way, if you're debugging your code, sometimes adding `NSLog` statements is helpful. You might want to create a `description` method for your `Person` class to facilitate that, though, so you can see the contents of your `Person` objects, e.g.:

```
- (NSString *)description
{
    return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Person (%p) {\n  theName = '%@'\n  theAge = %@\n}", self, self.theName, self.theAge];
}
```

This way, if you have a `Person` object named, say, `aRandomPerson`, you can then have a statement like:

```
NSLog(@"%@", aRandomPerson);
```

Also, if you have a dictionary entry with `Person` objects, if you `NSLog` that dictionary, you'll now have a meaningful log statement. This may help you diagnose what's in your `NSDictionary` items (if it really has `Person` objects rather than just `NSString` and `NSNumber` objects).

Comment: Great detailed answer, I actually made a typo in my personFromDictionary, it is actually a class method. But now I wonder what happens if that method gets called multiple times? Would that affect the behaviour?

Comment: @MrShoot No, if that's a class method, then that probably works. But your snippet that's invoking `updateEntries` is, at best, hard to follow, and possibly a little suspect. Perhaps in an effort to isolate us from irrelevant details you omitted some code that would place this in context. How is the `personFromDictionary` variable getting set (btw, using the same name for a method and a variable is very confusing)? Also, in entryDictionary you are setting the key kAge to a Person (but in `personFromDictionary` method, you suggest that this key would be a NSNumber). ...

Comment: @MrShoot In the `updateEntries` method, you also pass a `updatedDict`, and then you say that each key has a Person in it. Is it _really_ a dictionary for which every key contains a Person object? These are just a few random questions, but that `updateEntries` code just looks pretty darn weird. Also, it looks like you create a pool, but you have code before and after that pool. Is there any reason why this isn't all in the pool? Perhaps if you provide a slightly more complete snippet of that code, maybe we can make sense of this, but I can't make heads or tails of what you're trying to do.

Comment: @MrShoot if it helps, maybe we can continue discussion on http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/13016/object-being-released-too-early

Comment: @MrShoot BTW, I've made an update to my answer with a `description` method, that is very helpful if you want to insert `NSLog` statements in your code to diagnose the contents of various `Person` or `NSDictionary` objects. NSLog is your friend.

Comment: I'm noticing the crashes on random occurrences, I still can't figure out for the life of me what could be causing my crash. The updateEntries...I only put part of what the code is actually doing, since the method is fairly long and not necessarily relevant I believe. I tried going to the chat but was already too late. We could possibly try tomorrow. So far, I see how changing self.property = nil cause my crash. Although I do not know what part of my code is causing it (maybe a different thread trying to release the object?

Comment: I can totally see self.theName = nil calling the setter, which would in turn call release on the instance var name. Also, when calling NSMutableDictionary setObject:newPerson forKey:myKey that would also call a setter which would call release on the previous Person object, calling as a result the property release again. I was just confused. What are usually the best practices in these case.

Comment: using @property(nonatomic, retain) NSNumber *MYNumber; @synthesize MYNumber = _myNumber; then proper dealloc should be [_myNumber release]; instead of self.MYNumber = nil. What would the case be if instead of specifying retain on my property, making it "copy" I could get away with self.MYNumber = nil? It's quite tricky

Comment: I'll keep an eye out for you out on http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/13016/object-being-released-too-early